# How to send javascript codes to chrome with C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a disabled input at my website and i want to unlock it using C# program. I saw some questions but they're sending javascript to webbrowser event at program. I want to send js to another process with my program. How can i do it?

Like this; `document.getElementById('blabla').disabled = false;`

Answer (score 0):

Add a runat="server" attribute to your blabla Element, in code behind you can enable it like this:

```
blabla.Disabled= false;
```